# Reversing the zoomlevel?

Tags: leaflet

I'm creating an expanding map using leaflet, and wondering if it's possible to reverse the zoomlevel/requestedurl order with an easy way. I've checked this:

> zoomReverse   Boolean false   If set to true, the zoom number used in tile
>   URLs will be reversed (maxZoom - zoom instead of zoom)

This looks like this will do what I want, but what it really does is only reversing the requested url order.. (when a new level is added, it still needs to rename nudge every level to add the new one).

In other words, I'm looking for a way to address the closest zoom level as 0 and farthest zoom level as the biggest number.

I'm looking for a way that'll work without renaming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `maxZoom` (to the farthest zoom level's number) and `zoomReverse` (to true) for this to work.

Internally, leaflet does this:

```
_getZoomForUrl: function () {

    var options = this.options,
    zoom = this._map.getZoom();

    if (options.zoomReverse) {
        zoom = options.maxZoom - zoom;
    }

    return zoom + options.zoomOffset;
}
```

So its own administration remains unchanged, only the way it constructs the URLs is changed.

Comment: Ah, I see.. What I am actually looking for isto change the actual zoomlevel instead of doing something like zoom = options.maxZoom - zoom... I don't know if this makes any sense.

My reason for this is that I need to use map.getZoom() for the rest of my app

Comment: These configuration options change the mapping from the map's zoom level to the URL. Internally, the leaflet map will keep it's own administration the ordinary way.

Comment: Humm I see.. Actually a true reverse would be amazing.

Comment: You could add your own method `getReverseZoom()` to the map perhaps?